# Would you use the Product Schema.org type or the SoftwareApplication Schema.org type for a Wordpress (or something similar) plugin?

Tags: google-search, schema.org

My first thought was definitely SoftwareApplication but everything about [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/sw-app?) on the Schema.org type seems uncertain (except for when it comes to apps or games). At the top of the page they say:

> We are currently piloting this feature with a restricted set of initial data providers. We hope to soon open up the feature so any provider who implements spec-compliant markup is eligible to participate.

Their examples of how to implement the markup also include an application category that doesn't exist.

[image]

So after seeing all of that, **Product** then *seems* like the best Schema.org type but it doesn't *feel* like the best representation of the product; I've never seen Schema markup for a plugin. Does anyone have experience with Schema and plugins?

Comment: This is a question which suggests to me that you want opinions and it will likely be closed because of that. If you can reword it in a way where you expect more of a concrete answer, then it won't be closed.

Comment: Edited. Was that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SoftwareApplication, or more specifically [WebApplication](https://schema.org/WebApplication). Product is more for tangible items which can be physically obtained, whereas the former are specific types of CreativeWork.